# How to set box-shadow to an <img> tag which has an image with transparent corners? (CSS)

Tags: css, image, transparent, shadow, box-shadow

My image has transparent corners, like an icon. But how do I set a box-shadow for the  tag which is not square-shaped? I want a shadow which follows the shape of the current image. Is there any CSS solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it can be one using css filter... read about drop-shadow filter

```css
img{
  filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px  5px black)
}
```

```html
<img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/2cd43b_72a627d88d92466f94441a9bf97c6727~mv2.png" alt="png" width=200>
```